# Can the PC Version of Injustice: Gods Among Us link to the iOS version?

Tags: pc, ios, injustice-gods-among-us

Let me just say that at the current moment, Injustice: Gods Among Us is my favorite iOS fighting game. To me though, the charm of fighting games is to unlock all the characters. In the iOS version, with all the alternate versions and such, you can understand that it got me pretty busy. After a while, for some reason also due to the release of the New 52 Black Adam skin, I've decided to bite the bullet and consider buying the ultimate edition of the PC version, since I don't have an XBox 360, a PS3...Well, pretty much every current-gen console. Part of my intent is so that I can unlock the characters in the iOS that needs to be unlocked via console (New 52 Flash and Green Lantern, Knightfall Bane, Prison Superman, Batman Beyond and Arkham Harley Quinn.) So I was wondering, is the PC version like the consoles? Can I link it to my WBID so I can unlock the iOS unlocks on the "Console"? And also vice versa, use the "console" to unlock stuff on the iOS?

Comment: did you already try linking them?

Comment: Stupid me, not clarifying. I mean, I wanted to buy the PC version, but am still thinking about it. Whether it can link or not will really affect the final decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it most definitely does! I just bought Injustice on Steam after playing it a bunch on my iPad, and I can guarantee that the two accounts link perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, I actually took a leap of faith and got the game. I can see there's an option to link to your WBID.